# Cache JSON for 1 second with Google CDN to reduce server load

Tags: google-cloud-cdn

I'm looking for a solution to reduce server load on my API. I thought it's a good idea to cache the content for 1 second, so the server will get only 1 requests each second instead of many. However, I wasn't able to make it work:

- **In `Use origin settings based on Cache-Control headers` mode:** the Google CDN ignores the `'Cache-Control', 'public, max_age=1'` header. It looks like I can't cache JSON in this mode, probably because of the missing `Content-Range` or `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header?
- **In `Force cache all content`  mode:** it actually works, but the minimum TTL is 1 minute, which is just too much for me. I'd like to update the content every second.

I'm quite surprised no one uses short-lived caches for API-s, since it can theoretically reduce load and maybe save costs when using with external APIs (eg. you don't need to pay twice if you request the same thing from an expensive API endpoint). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the *"Use origin settings based on Cache-Control headers"* cache mode, you can instruct Google Cloud CDN to cache a response for 1 second by including a `Cache-Control: public, max-age=1` response header.

The problem with your earlier attempt appears to be a typo: the correct directive is `max-age` (with a hyphen), not `max_age` (with an underscore).

Comment: Omg wow, I did not realize it, thank you. I'll test with the correct header...

Answer (score 2):

In order to cache an object, even if you are using the honor origin cache mode, you need to have a [valid `content-range`](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/caching#cacheability) header. Using the force cache all mode will decorate the object with the cache control directive Cloud CDN needs to cache the object, even if the origin doesn't have the directive- FORCE_CACHE_ALL basically takes whatever the origin pushes out and overwrites the cache control directive.

If you are using the UX, you are correct, the console doesn't allow you to set a lower TTL value; however, you can set a lower TTL via gCloud commands

```
gcloud compute backend-services update BACKEND_SERVICE_NAME --client-ttl=1 --default-ttl=1 --global
```

Comment: As a clarification, responses generally don't need a Content-Range response header to be cached by Google Cloud CDN. Content-Range is necessary only for 206 Partial Content responses. For other status codes, any framing other than TCP FIN is acceptable, i.e. any of Content-Length, Transfer-Encoding: chunked, h2 END_STREAM, or QUIC FIN will do.